# Change background color multiple times while scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax

I'm working on this project where I’m creating a website using parallax scrolling. It's supposed to be one long one pager. As you scroll down the page the background color is supposed to change when you get to each new section of the page.

I have spent days searching the web and also here on stackoverflow, but I haven't found anything that works in the way i want it to.

I found this script here on stack:

```
 var tStart = 100 // Start transition 100px from top
      , tEnd = 500   // End at 500px
      , cStart = [250, 195, 56]  // Gold
      , cEnd = [179, 217, 112]   // Lime
      , cDiff = [cEnd[0] - cStart[0], cEnd[1] - cStart[1], cEnd[1] - cStart[0]];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            var p = ($(this).scrollTop() - tStart) / (tEnd - tStart); // % of transition
            p = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, p)); // Clamp to [0, 1]
            var cBg = [Math.round(cStart[0] + cDiff[0] * p), Math.round(cStart[1] + cDiff[1] * p), Math.round(cStart[2] + cDiff[2] * p)];
            $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + cBg.join(',') +')');
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtZDZ/12/ Here is the fiddle

This script does exactly what I want, except that I only change color one time back and forth. I need it to change background color like 4-5 times while you scroll down the page. Also I would like it to have a smooth transition when changing colors like in the fiddle :)

I hope someone out there can help me with this or just point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance

Comment: why you want to do that with javascript/jQuery? it can be done by css html

Comment: @Sarfaraz, CSS doesn't support scroll, you need JS in this one!

Comment: @Safaraz I figured it was the best solution and I also wanted a sort of animated effect when it changed between the colors. But if it I can be done in html css that would be great. Can you show me how?

Comment: @drinchev Do you have a solution with JS then :)?

Comment: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zWfN/).

Comment: @Vucko is it possible to say specifically when the colors should change? For example: When you scroll 1500px down the page it turns green and another 1000px it turns red and so on?

Comment: @JonasNilsson you can googling with `parallax scrolling` keyword and you can see demos and also when you debug it you can understand how to do that.

Comment: @JonasNilsson here is a link for demo http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html

Comment: @JonasNilsson here you [go](http://jsfiddle.net/3zWfN/1/).

Comment: @Vucko Thanks. It's close to what I need. Can you maybe do like a smooth transition from color to color like this script http://jsfiddle.net/dtZDZ/12/ . Then I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Derived from Vucko - http://jsfiddle.net/G4j6d/

Comment: @miro But with this script I can't choose what color and when it should change, can I?  In Vucko's script I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gradient background using css :

```
body {
background-color: linear-gradient(red, blue, green, blue, red)
}
```

Scrolling down, your background will change. This method is a little bit "cheaty", but it works as it will loop when it arrives at the end of the background.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

You may assign as many colors as you like in your `colors` variable

```
var colors = [
     [250, 195, 56], // Gold
     [250, 0, 0],    // Red
     [0, 250, 0],    // Green
     [0, 0, 250],    // Blue
     [179, 217, 112] // Lime
];

var height = $('body').height() - window.innerHeight;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var steps = Math.floor(height / colors.length);
  var position = $(this).scrollTop();
  var currentStep = Math.floor(position / steps);
  if ( currentStep === colors.length ) currentStep = colors.length - 1;
  var rgb = $("body").css('background-color').replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');     
  var previousColor = colors[currentStep] || colors[0];
  var nextColor = colors[currentStep+1] || colors[colors.length-1];
  var percentFromThisStep = ( position - ( currentStep * steps ) ) / steps;
  if ( percentFromThisStep > 1 ) percentFromThisStep = 1;

  var newRgb = [
     Math.floor(previousColor[0] + ( ( nextColor[0] - previousColor[0] ) * percentFromThisStep )),
     Math.floor(previousColor[1] + ( ( nextColor[1] - previousColor[1] ) * percentFromThisStep )),
     Math.floor(previousColor[2] + ( ( nextColor[2] - previousColor[2] ) * percentFromThisStep ))
  ];

  $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb('+ newRgb.join(',') +')');
});
```

Demo here : http://jsbin.com/ulohif/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the script but I need to be able to choose when the different colors take place. Like Vucko did earlier. Like at a 1000px from the top turn red, 2000px from the top turn green and so on. Can you incorporate this in your script :)?

Comment: Well, you can figure it out by yourself from now on. Play with this code a bit.

Comment: Damn ;) But okay :) I'm pretty novice when it comes to scripts, but I will try

Comment: I know it’s a lot to ask but can you fix it for me? I really don't have any clue to be honest. I would appreciate it a lot :)