# Background color change on dynamic page

Tags: dynamic, colors, background

I am building a webstore, where the quantity of displayed products is dinamically changing, by pressing "Show more" button. Background color should be changing multiple times while scrolling down and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414666/change-background-color-multiple-times-while-scrolling-down-the-page) article, which solves this problem, but it has fixed page height. Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a parameter to control the adaption rate and set this according to your needs if you don't know the page size on forehand (because a dynamic load for instance).

```
cStart = [250, 195, 56]  // Gold
  , cEnd = [179, 217, 112]   // Lime
  , cDiff = [cEnd[0] - cStart[0], cEnd[1] - cStart[1], cEnd[1] - cStart[0]];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var speed = 0.0005;
        var p = $(this).scrollTop()* speed; 
        p = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, p)); // Clamp to [0, 1]
        var cBg = [Math.round(cStart[0] + cDiff[0] * p), Math.round(cStart[1] + cDiff[1] * p), Math.round(cStart[2] + cDiff[2] * p)];
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + cBg.join(',') +')');
    });
});
```